# Java collection with polymorphic references

Tags: java, collections, polymorphism, abstract-class

I'm a beginner in Java programming and would like to understand what is the right way for working with polymorphic references here.

Suppose we have the following (abstract) code in C++:

```
List<Fruit*> lstFruit;
...
// collect apples here
while (...)
{
  Fruit* apple = new Apple("green");
  lstFruits.append(apple);
}
...
lstFruit[i]->doSomething(); // here is our virtual method
```

Java doesn't let me create a `List` collection with references to a base class that is `abstract`. What should I do in this situation? My goal is to work with different objects of child classes universally, no matter what their class actually is.

Comment: Answer from fiver is correct. Could you please provide code sample which you've tried in Java?

Comment: List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a generic collection with astract class:

```
List<Fruit> l = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
l.add(new Apple());
l.get(0).someFunctionOnFruit();
```

Comment: note that the base class is abstract so I get the error from Java: "Cannot instantiate the type List<Fruit>".

Comment: List is an interface in Java - you may instantiate ArrayList however.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Fruit or Apple - it's the List that is abstract.